# Detecting database persistence failure in PlayFramework

Tags: java, database, playframework, persistence, playframework-1.x

I am building an application with Playframework 1.2x

I have to detect if a database operation succeeded or not while doing CRUD operations

Here is what I have till now

```
public static void create(Args..) {
        Model m = new Model(Args..);
        m.save();
        if(m.id == null) {
        // Render failure Response
        }else {
        // Render Success Response
        }
}

public static void read(long id) {
        Model m = Model.findById(id);
        if(m == null ) {
            // Render failure Response
        }else{
            // Render Success Response
        }
}
```

I am not really sure as to what has to be done for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

The above method is not very elegant .  Is there a better solution for this, like Exceptions ?

I tried shutting down the database server that gives me a `PersistenceException` is this the way to go ? are there more exceptions similar to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you have a database connection problem you will have some exception that will be thrown by the ORM. PersistenceException is the root of JPA exceptions so if the exception is detected by the ORM you have this kind of exception.

For me, catching unexpected exceptions is not the way to go. If you have this kind of technical problem, your database will rollback you crud operation and nothing will be save.

Just catch exception that mean something for the user and let the other ones go up, then play will show a generic 500 page in this case

Comment: So you mean to say that I should not worry about doing any of the above validations ?

Comment: yes, a database failure is a technical problem, as there is nothing the user can do to overcome it, you just have to show him a sorry page in this case. As the transaction is not commited there is not impact on the data layer